# Button.titleLabel setTextColor: not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

I write a button and I want to change the text color of the button when i touch it. The code is like:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
[self.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];   
}
```

But it didnt work. Instead, I write

```
[self setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor]       forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

and it worked.
But I dont know the difference. Does anyone know about it, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is quite discussed in the apple [UIButton Class Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/titleLabel)

> Although this property is read-only, its own properties are
>   read/write. Use these properties primarily to configure the text of
>   the button. For example:

```
UIButton *button                  = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeSystem];
button.titleLabel.font            = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 12];
button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode   = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
```

> Do not use the label object to set the text color or the shadow color.
>   Instead, use the `setTitleColor:forState:` and
>   `setTitleShadowColor:forState:` methods of this class to make those
>   changes.

The titleLabel property returns a value even if the button has not been displayed yet. The value of the property is nil for system buttons.

Comment: @melody5417: definitely! (^_-) ... You can mark this as the answer to help others find this.. :)

Comment: haha, sorry,(*^_^*) i am new to here and  not familiar with this.

Comment: @melody5417, okay.. hmm.. clicking the check icon below the vote counter will mark the answer as the correct one, it will serve as identifier that the answer solved the issue and useful.. hmm..

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just know that I should click the check to mark the accepted answer.